# Laravel Display Per Page

Tags: php, laravel

Spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out but cant seem to find a solution. I need help with a table display per page feature. I'm struggling to figure out how to append to url a `?displayPerPage=10` parameter.

I've tried laravel's url() function but it just gives me /displayPerPage/10
I have also tried Request::fullUrl(), but it accept any arguments.

I was thinking of writing a function in jquery that will append to url, but there is gotta be a better way. Any help appreciated!!

**EDIT:** I need to do this in view, since i have a drop down in my table for the user to select how many results per page they want to display

P.S. I'm using laravel 5.1 on WAMP

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/generating-a-route-with-a-query-string-parameter

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html has a great helper function `link_to_route` that allows this: `link_to_route('route.name', $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());`

Comment: thats almost what I am looking for, however, I just rearranged my code to use the link_to_route method and it erases my other parameters, `orderBy=total_payment&sortBy=DESC`, and replaces with `displayPerPage=10`, i need something that will append the url

Comment: Include the other variables in the parameters array. You might want to use  [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: I ended up writing a helper function that includes `link_to_route()` or just `route()` and included all of the parameters `sortBy, orderBy and displayPerPage` this way the url has all of my variables that I need to change on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<a href="{{route('my-route')}}?perPage=10">link</a>
```

And now from your controller, you can get it like this:

`$request->input('perPage')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i do that, wount it erase my other parameters such as, sortBy and orderBy?

Comment: If the parameters you are passing varying? Like are you passing more than one parameter?

Comment: Here is what i currently have in there: ?orderBy=date&sortBy=DESC, so to this I need to append a &displayPerPage=10. This needs to be from view as the user can select how many they want to see per page. Also, I have a laravels paginator on a table working as well.

Comment: Something like this? `<a href="{{route('my-route')}}?orderBy=date&sortBy=DESC&perPage=10">link</a>`

Comment: So, are you using laravel paginator for displaying the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple route:

```
Route::get('/displayPerPage/{perPage}',  'MyController@index');
```

Then in controller:

```
public function index($perPgae)
{
    $pages = Data::paginate($perPage);
```

As alternative, you could just add to URL something like '/books?perpage=10&orderby=something&order=desc'. And then in controller use this data:

```
$perPage = Input::get('perpage');
$orderBy = Input::get('orderby');
$order = Input::get('order');
$pages = Data::orderBy($orderBy, $order)->paginate($perPage);
```

Another way to do that is using Laravel Collective or simple form with single button:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Get', 'route' => array('myroute.edit', 10))) !!}
    <button class="btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And then in controller:

```
public function edit($perPage)
{
```